# Stepping through my code works, running my code gives a "Method 'ShapeRange' of object 'Selection' failed" error message

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

Stepping through my Code Works and it does exactly what I want it to (create a powerpoint slide from various tables, text boxes and images from Excel). But Running the code doesn't work. I don't think it's to do with time as I have included a time pause after pasting in the range. When the Code gets to the "newpowerpoint.activewindow.selection..." line I get a "Method 'ShapeRange' of object 'Selection' failed"  error message.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

```
Sub CreatePowerPoint()

    Worksheets("2 Source of Change and Switchi").Select

    Dim newPowerPoint As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim activeSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
    Dim cht As Excel.ChartObject

    On Error Resume Next
    Set newPowerPoint = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")
    On Error GoTo 0

    newPowerPoint.Visible = True

    newPowerPoint.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlidenewPowerPoint.ActivePresentation.Slides.count 
    Set activeSlide = newPowerPoint.ActivePresentation.Slides(newPowerPoint.ActivePresentation.Slides.count)


 '######################The Code below Copies and Pastes in My Values#####################

        Worksheets("3 Switching details – Actual v").Select


        ActiveSheet.Range(Range("D51"), Range("D51").End(xlDown)).Copy
        newPowerPoint.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PasteExcelTableSourceFormatting")
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))

        newPowerPoint.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Left = 640

end sub
```

Comment: Can you debug.print the type name of the selected object? Also read the remarks in this page https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff744664.aspx

Comment: Hello. Sorry I don't know how to do that, I have another Macro which says what my range is called and it says it's called "table 1". This is a range copied from an Excel Worksheet if that helps. I read the Remarks but I don't understand why this would work fine in step through mode but not in normal run mode.

Comment: `debug.print(typename(newPowerPoint.ActiveWindow.Selection))`

Comment: In the Immediate box it printed "Selection"

Comment: Can you try to insert this code before the line of error. 
`Dim Si As Single: Si = 640
 newPowerPoint.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Left = Si`

Comment: Hi... I Tried that but I'm getting the same error message - again if I step through my code it works fine

Comment: Well, something is interfering in the runtime and is causing that method to fail. Could it be the active window or the powerpoint object? Do you have multiple instances of powerpoint running? Try  `Set newpowerpoint = GetObject("MyPowerPointPresentationName").Application`

Comment: It's as if the `ExecuteMso` command isn't really executed until there the code is paused (either by stepping through or hitting a runtime error). I suggest you do the placement of the shape in a separate procedure.

Comment: Interestingly The Execute MSO command didn't seem to perform until ALL of my code had run (when I inserted another blank slide at the end of my code just before End Sub - the table I wanted on the previous slide was pasted into the new slide as if the Execute MSO line was the last thing before End Sub).

Comment: Eventually solved using a separate powerpoint based Macro which positioned the table

Comment: @Chris consider posting your solution and accepting it as the answer so that it's clear to future readers of this post that a solution was found.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this code to work around. It seems some-kind of interruption is needed to run the code properly.

```
    With Application.ActiveWindow.Selection
        MsgBox "Click ok"
    End With
```

Answer (score 0):

`Application.Wait` is unreliable, but you're on the right track as it is a "timing" issue.

`ExecuteMso` is an asynchronous task and the problem arises because the *next* line of your code attempts to execute *before* the `ExcecuteMso` method has completed (copy/paste from clipboard often encounters same sort of error). [So you should be able to avoid this with `DoEvents`, in a loop while checking the number of shapes on the slide has been incremented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33711293/powerpoint-vba-does-not-recognize-excel-table-during-run).

I would recommend using the `Sleep` function within the loop to minimize CPU usage, just declare it at the top of your module like:

```
Private Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal lngMilliSeconds As Long)
```

And then your `DoEvents` loop like:

```
ActiveSheet.Range(Range("D51"), Range("D51").End(xlDown)).Copy
activeSlide.Select  ' <~~ This may not be necessary, but added just in case.

Dim shapeCount as Long: shapeCount = activeSlide.Shapes.Count
newPowerPoint.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PasteExcelTableSourceFormatting")

Do
    Sleep 100
    DoEvents
Loop Until (activeSlide.Shapes.Count = shapeCount + 1)

' get rid of this next line and work with the slide/shape directly:
' XXX newPowerPoint.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Left = 640

activeSlide.Shapes(shapeCount+1).Left = 640
```

Answer (score -1):

Eventually solved using a separate powerpoint based Macro which positioned the table

Comment: Could you post the solution code you used because I am having the same issue.