# PowerPoint VBA does not recognize Excel table during run

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I have a peice of code which copies a range from my excel file and pastes it onto my activeslide in PowerPoint. After hours of attempts to get the range from excel pasted as a table (NOT an image), I found the below code to work successfully. Note: myPP = powerpoint application.

```
myPP.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "PasteExcelTableSourceFormatting"
myPP.CommandBars.ReleaseFocus
```

The problem is that when I execute the macro, the table is pasted, but vba does not recognize the table unless the code is stepped through. I've tested this with the below code. During execution the code is skipped entirely, but during step-through it triggers.

```
For Each shp In activeSlide.Shapes
   If shp.HasTable Then
       MsgBox shp.Name
   End If
Next
```

Below is the full code. Basically I just want the excel range to be pasted into my powerpoint as a table, and for that table to be expanded to fit the slide. I'm open to suggestions in revising it a bit. Thanks for your help

```
Dim myPP as Object
Dim activeSlide as Object
Dim shp as Object

Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(Cells(1,1), Cells(4,7)).Copy
Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate

myPP.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "PasteExcelTableSourceFormatting"
myPP.CommandBars.ReleaseFocus

Dim myTable As String
   For Each shp In activeSlide.Shapes
       If shp.HasTable Then
           MsgBox shp.Name
           myTable = shp.Name
       End If
   Next

With activeSlide.Shapes(myTable)
      .Left = 23
      .Top = 105
      .Width = 650
      .Height = 375
End With
```

For ASH

```
Dim myPP As Object          'Powerpoint.Application
Dim myPres As Object        'Powerpoint.Presentation
Dim activeSlide As Object   'Powerpoint.Slide


Set myPP = CreateObject("Powerpoint.Application")
myPP.Visible = True
Set myPres = myPP.Presentations.Add
myPP.ActiveWindow.ViewType = 1   'ppViewSlide
Set activeSlide = myPres.slides.Add(1, 12) 'ppLayoutBlank
```

Comment: Did you try to add `DoEvents` before the loop? And to add some waiting time for the operation to finish?

Comment: I don't know much about doevents, but that looks promising. You might be right in that the program is moving too quickly to register the table object. I'll look into both that and waiting time when I'm at a computer and let you know the results. Thanks

Comment: I tried adding  DoEvents & Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:5")) before the loop. Neither individually or combined had an affect on the table. The table is still not being recognized by VBA during execution.

Comment: I would like to reproduce the problem. I admit this is unexpected behavior. Could you please share with me the piece of code where you set the variables `myPP` and `activeSlide`?

Comment: I believe they are at the top of my third snipet of code in my original post. I'm using late binding here because my users will have 2010 and 2013 excel. I'll add the code I use to start the program to my original post

Comment: I managed to reproduce it. It happens with a very freshly created presentation. Will try to see why.

Comment: It works ok if I increase the wait time above 15 seconds.. but that's too much :/

Comment: Hmm yea that's a bit long. I'll try and see if the 15s delay can be reproduced on my end when I'm at a comp. This is frustrating.

Comment: I think I found a good workaround, please try my answer ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem comes from the fact that we cannot predict how much time the paste operation will last, and when it finishes. We need to wait for its completion.

```
' first let us count the shapes in the slide
Dim shapeCount As Integer: shapeCount = activeSlide.Shapes.Count
myPP.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "PasteExcelTableSourceFormatting"

Do '<~~ wait completion of paste operation
    DoEvents
Loop Until activeSlide.Shapes.Count > shapeCount

' Now, our table is the last in the shapes collection.
With activeSlide.Shapes(activeSlide.Shapes.Count)
    .Left = 23
    .Top = 105
    .Width = 650
    .Height = 375
End With
```

Comment: Awesome, I appreciate your help. I'm going to test this when I get back!

Comment: yeah fine. The nice thing is that this method waits just the necessary time, and it is not busy waiting actually because DoEvents releases the resources to the OS. :)

Comment: Are you able to replicate the error if you do `activeSlide.Shapes(1).Select: myPP.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ...`  ?  I've never had to use a DoEvents loop in PPT/Excel 2010 or 2013... just a thought and possible alternative :)  (of course, if there are no shapes on the slide, that may not work)

Comment: @DavidZemens There are no shapes in the slide since it is created with `ppLayoutBlank`. Also tried with `activeSlide.Select`, didnt fix it. I admit it is an unusual behavior, but well, it seems we have to wait since we are driving PowerPoint from Excel...

Comment: Yes that is unexpected behavior... I've never seen it before, whether driving from Excel binding PowerPoint, or PowerPoint binding Excel. Odd.

Comment: @DavidZemens may be the special thing here is that we are using `ExecuteMso "something"`. I might be wrong but from this problem and its solution, it seems to me that `ExecuteMso` uses the Windows messaging system, which makes it asynchronous.

Comment: @A.S.H Solution worked wonderfully. Appreciate your follow through with the problem. Cheers! - Marked as solved.

Comment: @Citanaf Glad it helped. Cheers :)

Comment: @A.S.H. that could be the case... I know I've used the ExecuteMso method before specifically for this sort of paste between applications. That's why it looks odd to me, even if the mso method has some quirks, they're not anything I've seen before :)

Comment: FWIW, I've seen something similar back when we had to use PasteFace to put custom colors/images on commandbar buttons.  When PPT was running in a virtual machine (and only some VMs at that), I had to toss in several DoEvents to get the PasteFace to work.

Comment: hmm, seems like single `DoEvent` call is enough for my Office 2013.