# when i extract from excel to PowerPoint shows automation error

Tags: excel, vba, automation, powerpoint

i have code that can extract from excel to PowerPoint but sometime shows automation error

i tried using return but it doesn't work

can u plz help me with this issue?

this is my code so far:
'''
Sub presntation()

```
Dim pptapp As PowerPoint.Application
Dim PPTPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim PPTSlide As PowerPoint.Slide

'Declare Excel Variables
Dim ExcRng As Range
Dim RngArray As Variant
Dim RngArray1 As Variant
'  On Error Resume Next
' x = x - 1
' e = e - 1
' h = h - 1


Dim oPPTApp As PowerPoint.Application
Dim oPPTFile As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim oPPTShape As PowerPoint.Shape
Dim oPPTSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
```

'intger ma jjsjks kskjsdkjsd

```
Dim Rng As Range
Dim h As Integer
Dim v As Integer
```

'intger1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111

```
Dim m As Integer
Dim s As Integer

p = 0

On Error GoTo errhandler

'errhandler:
'Resume Next
 Dim g As Integer
Dim e As Integer
Dim p As Integer 
'Do
'DoEvents
'Loop Until ie.readstate = readystate_complete
'Tate Complete
'Get the PowerPoint Application, I am assuming it's already open.
Set pptapp = New PowerPoint.Application
    pptapp.Visible = True

Set oPPTApp = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")

'Set a reference to the range you want to copy, and then copy it.
'Set Rng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B3:N9")
'   Rng.Copy

'Set a reference to the active presentation.
g = 0
m = 0
Dim o As Integer
o = 0
h = 1
e = 0
x = 0
errhandler:
If p = 1 Then
oPPTFile.Slides(s).Delete

If x = 0 Then
GoTo Go
'
Else
If x = Even.Value = True Then
s = s - 1
'x = x - 1
e = e - 1
GoTo Go
Else
s = s - 1
x = x - 2
e = e - 2
GoTo Go
End If
End If
Else
End If

'Populate our array
'  If x = 0 Then
'  Sheets("WBB2").Select
'  Else
' If x = 1 Then
'  Sheets("WBB3").Select
' Else
' End If
 'End If
'Create a new instance of PowerPoint

s = 1
e = 0

' Set pptapp = New PowerPoint.Application
'    pptapp.Visible = True

'Create a new Presentation
Set PPTPres = pptapp.Presentations.Add
 'RngArray = Array(Worksheets("Backup data1").Range("E9:O38"))

RngArray = Array(Worksheets("Backup data1").Range("E9:O38"), Worksheets("Backup 
data1").Range("E6:O8"), Worksheets("Backup data1").Range("E50:O79"), Worksheets("Backup 
data1").Range("E47:O49"), Worksheets("Backup data1").Range("E87:O116"), Worksheets("Backup 
data1").Range("E84:O86"), Worksheets("Backup data1").Range("E127:O156"), Worksheets("Backup 
data1").Range("E123:O125"), Worksheets("Backup data1").Range("E165:O195"), Worksheets("Backup 
data1").Range("E163:O165"), Worksheets("Backup data1").Range("E203:O232"), Worksheets("Backup 
data1").Range("E200:O202"), Worksheets("Backup data1").Range("E241:O270"), Worksheets("Backup 
data1").Range("E237:O239"), Worksheets("Backup data1").Range("C307:L314"), Worksheets("Backup 
data1").Range("D301:K303"), Worksheets("Backup data1").Range("C335:L340"), Worksheets("Backup 
data1").Range("D329:K331"), Worksheets("Backup data1").Range("C365:L372"), Worksheets("Backup 
data1").Range("D359:K361"), _
Worksheets("Backup data1").Range("C393:L396"), Worksheets("Backup data1").Range("D387:K389"), 
Worksheets("Backup data1").Range("C421:L428"), Worksheets("Backup data1").Range("D415:K417"), 
Worksheets("Backup data1").Range("C449:L455"), Worksheets("Backup data1").Range("D443:K445"), 
Worksheets("Backup data1").Range("C477:L479"), Worksheets("Backup data1").Range("D471:K473"), 
Worksheets("Backup data1").Range("C505:L510"), Worksheets("Backup data1").Range("D499:K501"), 
Worksheets("Backup data1").Range("A531:F544"), Worksheets("Backup data1").Range("B527:K529"))
'Loop through the range array, create a slide for each range, and copy that range on to the 
slide.
For x = LBound(RngArray) To UBound(RngArray)


Go:

    'Set a reference to the range
    Set ExcRng = RngArray(x)
    
    'Copy Range
    ExcRng.Copy
    
    'Enable this line of code if you recieve error about the range not being in the clipboard 
   - This will fix that error by pausing the program for ONE Second.
    
    
    Set oPPTFile = oPPTApp.ActivePresentation
    If h = 1 Then
    If m = 2 Then
     Set oPPTSlide = Nothing
   Set PPTSlide = Nothing
    x = x - (1 + g)
    Set PPTSlide = PPTPres.Slides.Add(x + 1, ppLayoutBlank)
   ' Application.Wait Now + #12:00:01 AM#
    m = 1
    x = x + (1 + g)
    s = s + 1
    g = g + 1
    Else
    m = m + 1
    Set PPTSlide = PPTPres.Slides.Add(x + 1, ppLayoutBlank)
    End If
    
    
    
 'Set PPTSlide = PPTPres.Slides.Add(x + 1, ppLayoutBlank)
  'x = x + 1

  'Set a reference to the slide you want to paste it on.
  Set oPPTSlide = oPPTFile.Slides(s)

 Else
 m = m + 1
 End If

 Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:02")
 p = 1
 'On Error GoTo errhandler

 'errhandler:
 'Resume Next
  'WARNING THIS METHOD IS VERY VOLATILE, PAUSE THE APPLICATION TO SELECT THE SLIDE
  For i = 1 To 5000: DoEvents: Next
  oPPTSlide.Select

'WARNING THIS METHOD IS VERY VOLATILE, PAUSE THE APPLICATION TO PASTE THE OBJECT
  For i = 1 To 10000: DoEvents: Next
 oPPTApp.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "PasteSourceFormatting"
 oPPTApp.CommandBars.ReleaseFocus
 For i = 1 To 10000: DoEvents: Next

 '
 If e < 14 Then
 If h = 2 Then

 With oPPTApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange

 .Top = 20
     .Left = 25
    .Width = 910
 End With
 Set oPPTSlide = Nothing
 Set PPTSlide = Nothing
 h = 0
 'Application.Wait Now + #12:00:01 AM#
 Else
 With oPPTApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange
    .Top = 80
    .Left = 50
    .Height = 450
    .Width = 870
   ' Application.Wait Now + #12:00:01 AM#
  End With
  End If
  Else
   If h = 2 Then
  With oPPTApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange
  .Top = 20
    .Left = 25
    .Width = 910
    Set oPPTSlide = Nothing
     Set PPTSlide = Nothing
  End With
   h = 0
   Else
  With oPPTApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange
    .Top = 80
    .Left = 50
    .Height = 300
  '   .Height = 200
    .Width = 870
  End With

  End If
  End If


  o = o + 1
  e = e + 1
    'Create a new Slide
    'Set PPTSlide = PPTPres.Slides.Add(x + 1, ppLayoutBlank)
   
    'Paste the range in the slide as a linked OLEObject
   'PPTApp.CommandBars.ExecuteMso
    'PPTSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPasteOLEObject
  ' pptApplication.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PasteSourceFormatting")
   h = h + 1
  Next x



 End Sub
```

Comment: Start by quoting the *exact* error message and mentioning which line of code it occurs on.

Answer (score 0):

You're using 'Set oPPTFile = oPPTApp.ActivePresentation'

Depending what you do during the macro is running, PowerPoint might lose the focus, then the 'ActivePresentation' is empty.
Some lines before you use 'Set PPTPres = pptapp.Presentations.Add'

As a quick workaround try 'Set oPPTFile = PPTPres' instead of 'Set oPPTFile = oPPTApp.ActivePresentation', for future projects: If you already assigned an object to a variable, use this variable instead of the ActivePresentation.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you are not waiting long enough for the paste to be completed. Try the method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33711293)

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub presntation()

    ' Power point variables
    Dim oPPTApp As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim oPPTPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
    Dim oPPTShape As PowerPoint.Shape
    Dim oPPTSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
   
    ' Excel Variables
    Dim xl As Excel.Application
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim i As Long, RngArray As Variant, p As Integer, t0 As Single
    Dim n As Integer
    t0 = Timer
    RngArray = Array("E9:O38", "E6:O8", "E50:O79", "E47:O49", _
                     "E87:O116", "E84:O86", "E127:O156", "E123:O125", _
                     "E165:O195", "E163:O165", "E203:O232", "E200:O202", _
                     "E241:O270", "E237:O239", "C307:L314", "D301:K303", _
                     "C335:L340", "D329:K331", "C365:L372", "D359:K361", _
                     "C393:L396", "D387:K389", "C421:L428", "D415:K417", _
                     "C449:L455", "D443:K445", "C477:L479", "D471:K473", _
                     "C505:L510", "D499:K501", "A531:F544", "B527:K529")
    
    ' Get the PowerPoint Application, I am assuming it's already open.
    'Set oPPTApp = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")

    ' Create new presentation
    Set oPPTApp = New PowerPoint.Application
    oPPTApp.Visible = msoTrue
    Set oPPTPres = oPPTApp.Presentations.Add(msoTrue)
    
    ' create slides
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set xl = wb.Parent
    For i = LBound(RngArray) To UBound(RngArray) Step 2
   
        ' create slide
        If i Mod 2 = 0 Then
            p = p + 1
            oPPTPres.Slides.Add p, ppLayoutBlank
        End If
        xl.StatusBar = "Creating slide " & p
       
        Set oPPTSlide = oPPTPres.Slides(p)
        oPPTSlide.Select
    
        'Copy Top Range
        wb.Worksheets("Backup data1").Range(RngArray(i + 1)).Copy
        n = oPPTSlide.Shapes.Count
        oPPTApp.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "PasteExcelTableSourceFormatting"
        ' wait for shape to be created
        Do
            DoEvents
        Loop Until oPPTSlide.Shapes.Count > n
        
        With oPPTSlide.Shapes(oPPTSlide.Shapes.Count)
            .Top = 20
            .Left = 25
            .Width = 910
        End With
        xl.CutCopyMode = False
    
        'Copy Bottom Range
        wb.Worksheets("Backup data1").Range(RngArray(i)).Copy
        n = oPPTSlide.Shapes.Count
        oPPTApp.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "PasteExcelTableSourceFormatting"
        ' wait for shape to be created
        Do
            DoEvents
        Loop Until oPPTSlide.Shapes.Count > n
        
        With oPPTSlide.Shapes(oPPTSlide.Shapes.Count)
            .Top = 80
            .Left = 50
            .Width = 870
            If i < 14 Then
               .Height = 450
            Else
               .Height = 300
            End If
        End With
        xl.CutCopyMode = False
       
    Next i

    AppActivate xl.Caption
    xl.StatusBar = "Done"
    MsgBox p & " slides created", vbSystemModal, Format(Timer - t0, "0.0 secs")

End Sub
```